# passing strings to batch file through ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, batch-file, format

I am using Java ProcessBuilder to pass a String to a batch file as an argument.

> ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
>                   "batch.bat",
>                   "jason mary molly");

The batch file...

```
 @ECHO OFF
 SET V1=%1
 ECHO %V1%
 pause
```

The batch file output is this (*pay attention to the double quotes*):

"jason mary molly"

If I pass in only 1 string there are no quotes to be found! My problem is, I have a rather complex program I am writing that requires these 3 arguments to not have quotes around them, or they will be viewed by the program as one file name rather than 3 seperate arguments. Is there a way to remove these double quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `%~1` It should get rid of the quotes

For more information type: `for /? | more +121` in cmd. Here is the quote reference:

```
%~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
%~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
%~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
%~pI        - expands %I to a path only
%~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
%~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
%~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
%~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
%~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
%~zI        - expands %I to size of file
%~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
               environment variable and expands %I to the
               fully qualified name of the first one found.
               If the environment variable name is not
               defined or the file is not found by the
               search, then this modifier expands to the
               empty string
```

#### The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:

```
%~dpI       - expands %I to a drive letter and path only
%~nxI       - expands %I to a file name and extension only
%~fsI       - expands %I to a full path name with short names only
%~dp$PATH:I - searches the directories listed in the PATH
               environment variable for %I and expands to the
               drive letter and path of the first one found.
%~ftzaI     - expands %I to a DIR like output line
```

Comment: ok, now if you can answer why I didn't post this 2 hours ago? It worked! Thank you very much

Comment: am planning on it, just need to wait a few more minutes before it will let me:)

Comment: oh yea, forgot about the time mechanics. TY

Answer (score 1):

Each `String` you pass to `ProcessBuilder` becomes an argument to the command you are executing, so using

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( "batch.bat", "jason mary molly");
```

Means you are passing **1** argument to your command, not three.

Try using...

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( "batch.bat", "jason", "mary", "molly");
```

Instead

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I dont have the option to pass the arguments as seperate parameters